# Hyperlink to a file in include_path

Tags: php

I am trying to understand how to have a require_once directive point to a php file located in a folder belonging to a path specified in a php.ini include_path.  This folder is located before public_html.  Here is, roughly, the web structure as it stands:

```
   .cpanel
   .cpanel-datastore
   access-logs
   etc
   include_path
        /folder1
             //session.php
             //db_connection.php
             //functions.php
   public_html
        /folder
             //File_with_require_once.php
   ssl
```

Now, of course, the php.ini file is located in public_html

And the question again is, in File_with_require_once.php, when I make the call for :

```
<?php require_once("????????/session.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("????????/db_connection.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("????????/functions.php"); ?>
```

What do I write instead of the question marks?

I hope I am being clear... Can somehow help?  Thank you.

Comment: `../../include_path/folder1/session.php` ?

Comment: "Now, of course, the `php.ini` file is located in `public_html`". Why would it be there?

Comment: Your document root is /public_html. Nobody has access to the upper folder than /public_html. Well, "../../include_path" is your answer but it won't work for you.

Comment: I agree with you that no one will be able to access the folder and that is the whole point, for security sake.  But this folder was included in the include_path of my php.ini file in which case, my application can access it but how do I call it within <?php require_once("????????/functions.php"); ?>